# How do I get the value of a gridview Cell?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cells

How can I get the value of a `gridview` cell?  I have been trying the code below with no luck.

```
protected void grvExpirations_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
  int test = Convert.toInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void grvExpirations_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
       int test = Convert.toInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {   
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
        {  
             string LinkText = (string)System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RegistrationLinkText"); 
            if(LinkText == "text")  
            {  
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "your text"; 
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code below,

```
 protected void grvExpirations_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int test = Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[5].Text.Trim()));
        }
    }
```

and please remember cell index number starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

If you use the above methods you will get the value of cell[5] for the last row only. 
So if you are specific about a certain row I think you can get the value from any other gridview event handlers.