# Get the value of a cell in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I ve a gridview with checkbox in my aspx page. The gridview is bound using typed dataset. How do I retrieve the value in the first cell of gridview? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of a gridview Cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549341/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-gridview-cell)

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if you got the info you want....

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
foreach(GridViewRow dr in Gridview.Rows)
{
   string text = dr.Cell[0].Text;
}
```

of for single row

```
   string text = GridView1.Rows[row_number].Cell[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
int result = Convert.toInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```