# Can't assign printable object to string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

With the following line of code I am able to print the primary keys of the rows:

```
protected void storyGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PK_NonScrumStory"));
}
```

[image]

However I can't assign the value to a string variable:

[image]
and
[image]

How can I get the value assigned to a variable?

EDIT:

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   user_nonscrumstories2.storyGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in c:\Users\tunnelld2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Websites\ZSA_New 21\user\nonscrumstories2.aspx.cs:424
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +181
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +2188
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception to the question?

Comment: I have added the stack trace.

Comment: @LeastOne is correct, this was the issue thanks. Post the answer if you would like credit.

Comment: @DavidTunnell, removed the comment and added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at this post [How do I get the value of a gridview Cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549341/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-gridview-cell), notice how it only attempts to retrieve values for rows that are of type `DataControlRowType.DataRow`. Your null reference exception might result from attempting to get the non-existent `"PF_NonScrumStory"` value from the header row.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to call `ToString()` on the object, but a `NullReferenceException` is probably happening because the object is null. When you debug and it stops on the exception, look at the locals (Debug -> Windows -> Locals) to see what its actual value is.

Comment: The object is null, but not when it prints, only when I am assigning it to a variable. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly casting to (int) to get rid of "boxing" and then call .ToString()